# Adding methods to default Objects in obj c and swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

Hello I have been looking around for this answer and I've come across multiple articles but none of them have given me a straight answer. Lets say we have Object Date in objective C if I want to add methods to this object I would create a file similar to this:

obj c:

```
@interface Date (AdditionDate)
//methods
@end
```

in swift it seems to be a little different we do the following:

```
extension Date {
//methods
}
```

is this correct? Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep that's correct. What you are looking for is called a category in Objective-C terminology. It is the ability to add on methods to an existing class even if you don't have the original source code for that class. Keep in mind that you can't use categories to store any state on the original object, so instance variables are off the table.

Comment: Awesome thank you so much for the explanation! this answers my question!